# Adding numbers with asymmetric uncertainties

Tags: error-propagation

I need to add a series of numbers with asymmetric standard deviations, such as
$$5_{-2}^{+1} \,+ \,3_{-3}^{+1}.$$
Although I know it's common to add the upper errors ($\sigma_{\scriptsize{+}}$) and the lower errors ($\sigma_{\scriptsize{-}}$) separately in quadrature, I also know that this is not correct.

I don't know the underlying probability distribution, but reading [this note by Barlow (2004)](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0406120v1), it seems that a Gaussian whose width depends on the value of $x$ is acceptable for a range of PDFs, at least in the case where one is interested in the average of the two numbers obtained for the same experiment ("combination of results").

That is, assuming that the variation in standard deviation is linear
$$\sigma(x) = \sigma + \sigma'(x-\hat{x}),$$
with
$$\sigma = \frac{2\sigma_{\scriptsize{+}}\sigma_{\scriptsize{-}}}{\sigma_{\scriptsize{+}} + \sigma_{\scriptsize{-}}} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \mathrm{and}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \sigma' = \frac{\sigma_{\scriptsize{+}} - \sigma_{\scriptsize{-}}}{\sigma_{\scriptsize{+}} + \sigma_{\scriptsize{-}}},$$
the likelihood of the distribution is given by
$$\ln L(\hat{x};x) = -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\hat{x}-x}{\sigma(x)}\right)^2.$$

This can also be done taking the variance, rather than the std. dev., as linear.

In reality the numbers that I need to add are probably more evenly distributed in log space than in linear space, but I don't know if that makes any difference.

In addition to the 68% confidence interval, I'm also interested in the higher C.I. values for the results, i.e. the 95%, 99%, etc., but I don't know if that's possible given that I have only the 68% C.I. for the numbers.

I should say that I'm not very good at statistics, so please keep answers at a not-too-high level, if possible.

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question? Myself I am also dealing with asymmetric errors from a MCMC ouput distribution. I would like to perform a linear regression on those values but first I would need some equivalent symmetric error... I am reading the article from Barlow 2004 but the applet is not longer available. I was thinkin on using the first equation you wrote and assume a linear standard deviation from the upper and lower values... What do you think?

Comment: Hi Delosari. I couldn't really get that approach to work. Instead I ended up making my own Python code — based on [Barlow (2003)](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0306138v1) — that is able to reproduce the results in [this applet](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/~barlow/java/statistics5.html) which works (for me, in Firefox). I'll put the code on GitHub at some point, but if you're interested, drop me a line; you can find my info on my SE profile.

Comment: I'll write up an answer, but in the meantime interested viewers can download my code for adding asymmetric uncertainties on [github.com/anisotropela/add_asym](https://github.com/anisotropela/add_asym).

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. You cannot be dealing with Gaussian distributed data if you are claiming that you have asymmetrical uncertainties on a measurement. A Gaussian has a single width it does not have two different $\sigma$ 's. Probably what you have here are data where the underlying distribution is not gaussian, and you want to present a certain confidence level limit, which may be asymmetrical. Not exactly a full answer but should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I don't know what kind of model/data you are dealing with, but I would instinctively solve this problem using MC methods. In other words: Run your experiment many times (10000 or more times), and look at the output distribution of central values. Integrate this distribution from the mean and you will find your 90 % / 95 % / 68 % or whatever confidence level limit.

Comment: @user3728501 No no, the question is about asymmetric PDFs, _not_ Gaussian PDFs. The reason I mention Gaussians in the text is because the method that Barlow 04 use is based on a Gaussian, but where the value of $\sigma$ is a function of $x$ (see Secs. 3.5 and 3.6 in the source). Your approach would be fine if I could just run my experiment 1000 times, but each simulation took several months, so that wasn't possible. But I ended up using another method, that seemed to give acceptable results. I describe it in App. B of [this paper](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2019A%26A...627A..84L).

Comment: @pela Ok thanks for clarifying, for future readers this is what I was thinking: Adding in quadrature can only be done for Gaussian distributed data, in which case the $1\sigma$ limits would be the same for positive and negative confidence limits. This is not the case in this question. However as explained this does not apply.

Comment: @user3728501 sorry if it was confusing, I’m no statistician :) I just mentioned the quadrature adding because it’s common practice (at least in my field, astronomy), even though it’s wrong and has no statistical foundation.

Comment: @pela That will be true, because many measurements in physics are Gaussian